# WSDL fail. Not a programming issue.

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I've run hundreds of web services and test methods for a project.  Now a new portion of the project fails because of the wsdl and I'm at a loss.  I'll view the webservice in chrome and when you click on the wsdl it does nothing.  which is why my testmethod fails and i receive the no endpoint listening.  I'm calling a webservice and passing an XML string.  Im 99% positive that it isn't an issue with the code but rather something in visual studio itself.

Comment: What does "fails" mean?  Exception, error, nothing happens, etc?  If you run in the debugger, are any output message shown?

Comment: Communication through Code will be effective...

Comment: You get an exception, No endpoint listening.  The only thing that seems to work is to delete the port number, change it, and then change it back.  I don't want to permanently change it to something other than the original because everything in the project points to the same port.  Changing the port and then reverting seems to be a temporary fix but I have to do this every 5 or so times I run the test

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the way around this was to always clean the services file, then build it every time I wanted to run the test.  It's not ideal but it works